# Как сделать проверку папок на определенные файлы + авто разброс если найдены [Java]

Tags: java

Как сделать проверку папок на определенные файлы? к примеру в коде указать путь до файла к примеру **C:\War\configs\amd-64.ax** и другие только мне надо на несколько папок сделать эту проверку **War_0 - War_1 - War_2 - War_3 - War_4** думаю суть понятна если файлы которые указанны в коде программы на Java найдены то она должна их перенести в другую папку к примеру она должна так-же разбросать по 5 указанным в коде папкам с другим путем **C:\War\config\War\War_1** и т.д

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вообще у папки можно попросить список файлов, с заданным фильтром по имени файла.
Подробнее [тут](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/file_listfiles_filename_filter.htm)